# When are these inequalities consistent?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Let $x_i,y_i \in \mathbb{R}$. Consider the following set of inequalities.
\begin{align}
x_1-x_2 &\leqslant y_1 \\
x_2-x_3 &\leqslant y_2 \\
&\vdots \\
x_{n-1}-x_n &\leqslant y_{n-1} \\
x_n-x_1 &\leqslant y_n \\
\end{align}
If they are consistent, necessarily $\sum_{i=1}^n y_i \geqslant 0$.

Is that also a sufficient condition of feasibility?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: consider $x_1=y_1+y_2+\ldots+y_n$, $x_2= y_2+\ldots+y_n$, $x_3= y_3+\ldots+y_n$, ... , $x_n = y_n$.